# set GameObject to Script's public variable pragmatically?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I'm trying to make decision in my script if I get a value 1 then run specific game object which is (`PopulationGenerator` of population engine asset). I have 3 population generator in my scene but I can't assign any of them pragmatically in the code to `PopulationGenerator` variable.

The only way is drag and drop gameobject from side menu on the script in the unity GUI.

This is the code:

```
public PopulationGenerator generate1;

generat1.totalToSpawn = Convert.ToInt32(number) - 5;
```

Can i set one of Population Generators in scene like for example

```
if (value == 1)
    generate1 = gameobject.name("generator1");
else if (value == 2)
    generate1 = gameobject.name("generator2");
...
```

Is there any method to set a gameobject of any type to a variable in the code ?
Thanks.

Comment: `generat1.totalToSpawn = Convert.ToInt32(number) - 5;` Can you guarantee that 'number' will always allow conversion to an int? What happens if someone enters a string? Use Int32.TryParse()

Comment: `GameObject.Find(name)`? Though your field is of type `PopulationGenerator` which is a *component of* a GameObject, so you'd need `GetComponent<PopulationGenerator>()` as well.

Comment: You could do instead `if (value < generateCount) generate1 = gameobject.name($"generator{value}"); and save on code.

Comment: number entered automatically

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
generate1 = GameObject.Find("nameOfGenerator").GetComponent<PopulationGenerator>();
```